# forced by jQuery to keep reference of "this" in Backbone views

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, this

Most of the functions in my backbone.js views start with `var that = this;` because inside some of the jQuery helper functions `this` doesn't refer to the backbone view any more. See lines 08 and 14 in the dummy sample below.

```
01. var WhateverView = Backbone.View.extend({
02.     el: '#foo',
03.     fooText: 'test',
04.     fooArray: [1, 2, 3],
05.     ajax1: function() { ... },
06.     ajax2: function() { ... },
07.     render: function() {
08.         var that = this;
09.         $.when(this.ajax1(), this.ajax2()).done(function(a1, a2) {
10.             that.renderPage(a1, a2);
11.         });
12.     },
13.     renderPage: function(a1, a2) {
14.         var that = this;
15.         $.each(this.fooArray, function(i) {
16.             alert(that.fooText);
17.         });
18.     }
19. });
```

Is there a way in backbone (or javascript in general) avoid this?

Comment: Using `that` is, in my opinion, a bad practice. It breaks as soon as you nest callbacks and it lacks the semantic to let you read the code. Here, I would have used `var view = this;`. In practice (but I don't use your specific framework) I don't find this to be so problematic neither so frequent.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Makes sense and will use it. The question still holds though.

Comment: Yes, the question still holds, especially if it's specific to backbone : this particular structure seems very prone to this problem that is less frequent in more idiomatic (framework free) javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: 
`$.each(this.fooArray, $.proxy(function(i) {
             alert(this.fooText);
         }, this));`

or if you're using backbone with underscore you could do: 
`$.each(this.fooArray, _.bind(function(i) {
             alert(this.fooText);
         }, this));`

or natively(but don't work in all browsers): 
`$.each(this.fooArray, function(i) {
             alert(this.fooText);
         }.bind(this));`

hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid "var that = this"  if possible.

My pattern for solving this is to use the underscore bindAll method in intialize of all views (and models too) to guarantee that when a function is called, this is the expected object.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({ // or model, or collection
  initialize: function (options) {
    _.bindAll(this);
    // your intitialze stuff
  }
});
```

You can also use the _.each method instead of $.each, which will allow you to pass the context of this to the iterator function.

```
_.each(someArrayOrCollection, function(x, y) {
  //whatever
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could write, with pure js :

```
    renderPage: function(a1, a2) {         
       $.each(this.fooArray, (function(that){
         return function(i) {
             alert(that.fooText);
           };
       })(this));
    }
```

but I'm afraid it is not as readable as `var that = this;`

Hope this will help anyway